# how to use python modules in an android app developed by kivy?

Tags: python, android, excel, kivy

I want to create a simple android app that modifies values in an existing excel file .

The application is developed using Python and using the kivi package , my problem is I dont know how can i use a module like openpyxl in the python code with a way that the kivy knew it .

NOTE: When I run the using the kivy launcher, the app turn off befor showing any thing .

NOTE 2: I think it's because of the import statment of the openpyxl module .

These are the modules I need

```
from kivy.app import App    
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout    
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty    
import openpyxl
```

Comment: Don't guess what's wrong, [debug it](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform). To learn about including modules in your app, read the python-for-android or buildozer documentation. I don't know if openpyxl will work, it may have compiled components and so need a build recipe that isn't currently supported.

Answer (score 0):

To debug difficulties at import, you can wrap the `import` statements:

```
try:
    import whatever_lib
except ImportError as exc:
    input("Import failed:" + str(exc) +"\nPress Enter to close")
```

Have you checked, in some interpreter, that these packages are installed?

Comment: i dont know how to install packages on android devices

Comment: the openpyxl  module is not installed by default .. i install it on windows using pip , how can install it on android

Comment: Then please update your question: this is about installing third-party python packages on android. I've no idea how/if you can do that though.